# C++, приоритет операторов

Tags: c++, операторы, приоритет

Рассмотрим следующий пример:

```
if (a() == b && c > d)
{
    // ...
}
```

Таблица приоритетов операций говорит следующее:

- `==`: 9, слева направо;
- `&&`: 13, слева направо;
- `>`: 8, слева направо.

Мне интуитивно понятно, что левая часть оператора `&&` должна выполняться первой. Если слева `true`, тогда выполняется правая часть. На практике так и происходит.

Но если верить таблице, то в первую очередь должна выполняться операция с наивысшим приоритетом, то есть `>`.

В `Стандарте` не определен порядок приоритетов. Этот порядок выводится из грамматики языка. Я не понимаю, что это значит.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь поможет разобраться в данном вопросе.

Comment: Всегда проще явно поставить скобки и не париться с приоритетами. Там более, что после трансляции в рантайме скобки не добавляют ни времени исполнения, ни объема кода. А расходы на трансляцию лишней пары скобок настолько мизерны, что об этом не стоит и говорить.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> левая часть оператора `&&` должна выполняться первой. Если слева true, тогда выполняется правая часть

Правильно.

> если верить таблице, то в первую очередь должна выполняться операция с наивысшим приоритетом

А здесь ошибка.

Приоритет и порядок вычисления - разные вещи. Приоритет, грубо говоря, влияет на воображаемую "расстановку скобок" в выражении.

Раз у `&&` приоритет ниже `==` и `>`, то из `a() == b && c > d` получается `(a() == b) && (c > d)`.

А дальше в дело вспупает [порядок вычисления](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> very value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of the built-in logical AND operator `&&` and the built-in logical OR operator `||` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, это именно то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score -2):

Сначала первая часть до И(&&) потом вторая (в случает если первая true). Данное поведение не зависит от приоритета, а от порядка. Ваша запись эквивалента

```
if (a() == b) {
    if (c > d) { 
         ...some code...
    }
}
```

И тут все выполняется исключительно по прямому порядку выполнения команд

Comment: Я знаю, чему эквивалентен мой код, большое вам спасибо. Какую смысловую нагрузку несет ваш ответ? Вы можете объяснить, в связи с чем представленный код чему-то эквивалентен? Можете привести ссылки на разделы `Стандарта`, в которых данный вопрос раскрывается?

Comment: @MGNeo Вам выше уже объяснили)